# I am getting a error which makes legit no sense it's is based on datastore, magnitude and .touched event

Tags: lua, roblox

I am making a mini project where i make a leaderstats, and then in the leader stats is the points, and when you leave and join, data sets and retrieves respectively, follows the player through magnitude, and changes the points when it gets touched by player, except im getting error sometimes, sometimes not

the script is:

```
local DatastoreService=game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local zombiePointIncrease=DatastoreService:GetDataStore("zombiePointIncrease")


game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    
    local leaderstats=Instance.new("Folder", player)
    leaderstats.Name="leaderstats"
    
    local points=Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    points.Name="points"
    local data
    local success, errormessage=pcall(function()
        data=zombiePointIncrease:GetAsync(player.UserId.. "-cash")
    end)    
    
    if success then
        points.Value=data
    else
        print("there was a error, getting your data")
    end
end)

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    local success, errormessage=pcall(function()
        zombiePointIncrease:SetAsync(player.UserId.. "-cash", player.leaderstats.points.Value)
    end)    
    
    if success then
        
        print("Data Successfully saved")
    else
        print("There was a error while saving your data")
        warn(errormessage)
    end
end)
```

All goes fine then i get a zombie model and make this script under it,
it basically looks for other players and follows them within the agroDistance:

```
local zombieHumanoid=script.Parent:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local zombieTorso=script.Parent:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")

local function findTarget()
    local agroDistance=100
    local target

    for i, v in pairs(game.Workspace:GetChildren()) do
        local human=v:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
        local torso=v:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart")

        if human and torso and v~=script.Parent then
            --check distance
            if (torso.Position-zombieTorso.Position).magnitude<agroDistance then
                agroDistance=(torso.Position-zombieTorso.Position).magnitude
                target=torso
                return target
            end
        end
    end
end

while wait(1) do
    local torso=findTarget()
    if torso then
        zombieHumanoid:MoveTo(torso.Position)
    else
        zombieHumanoid:MoveTo(zombieTorso.Position + Vector3.new(-50, 50),0,Vector3.new(-50,50))
    end
end
```

then i make this script where when the torso gets touched, the points increase:

```
local zombietorso=script.Parent.HumanoidRootPart
local Players=game:GetService("Players")

local function findHuman()
    for i,v in pairs(game.Workspace:GetChildren()) do
        local human=v:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
        local torso=v:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart")
        if human and torso and v~=script.Parent then
            local player=game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(v)
            local points=player.leaderstats.points
            points.Value=points.Value+1
        end
    end 
end

zombietorso.Touched:Connect(findHuman())
```

it seems as there is legit no problem in my code, no syntax error, nothing, atleast for what i know

but when the 3rd script is used i get error pointing to

```
zombieHumanoid:MoveTo(zombieTorso.Position + Vector3.new(-50, 50),0,Vector3.new(-50,50))
```

the error says "Enable to cast value to Object", when i remove the 3rd script it works fine sometimes even when the 3rd script is there, it works fine, is this a bug within roblox studio? wouldn't be surprised with roblox

I have legit tried everything i could, change script variables whatnot which would not have to do with script even using print statements to debug, it only works sometimes

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of problems with your code, the Vector3.new constructor method only accepts 3 arguments, not two, these are x, y and z.
As for the MoveTo method, it only accepts at max two arguments.

Modifying your code, it would look like so:

```lua
zombieHumanoid:MoveTo(Vector3.new(zombieTorso.Position + Vector3.new(-50, 50, 0),0,Vector3.new(-50,50, 0)))
```

I have added the value 0 as the Z vector in the vector3 constructors, as I'm not really sure what you want to achieve here.

Related documentation:
[MoveTo documentation](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Humanoid#MoveTo)
[Vector3 documentation](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/datatypes/Vector3#new)